# Should LED can lights be warm to touch when they are not on?

Tags: led, recessed-lighting

I recently had 8 old can lights converted to LED lights with kits bought at Home Depot. I noticed today that the lights themselves and an area around the lights is warm to the touch. They have not be on all day today or yesterday. The house is not warm either.  Should these be warm when they are not in use?

Comment: Do the fixture cans project up into an attic that might be warm or hot? Alternately  check to see if they are warm first thing in the morning, if you get up early enough (pretty early in the Northern Hemisphere right now.)

Comment: Did you see ver check fir warmth with old set up?

Comment: "converted to LED" - Were the entire cans replaced (remove the old fixture from the ceiling, install a whole new fixture), or was this kit something that was installed in the existing cans so LED bulbs could be installed?